# ghc-9.2.5 is not supported by haskell plugin in vscode but I can't use other ghc versions

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm new to Haskell and I am trying to setup haskell plugin in vscode using official haskell plugin but I came with up some problems with setting up code hinting and syntax recognition of hls plugin.

I have already installed ghc-9.2.4 and 9.2.3(by ghcup) since they are fully supported by the plugin but 9.2.5 which is recommended isn't supported. I also installed these two virsions in stack as well.

VsCode told me that `HLS does not support GHC 9.2.5 yet` so at first I tried to change my ghc version to 9.2.4 but I don't know how. I also tried to reinstall stack and reinstall ghc in stack but also failed.

Sometimes command line just report " `YAML parse exception at line 9, column 18: mapping values are not allowed in this context`" when I try to use stack command after reinstalling stack and ghc.

So I'd like to ask about how to decide which ghc to use in the setting manually, or if there is another way to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: `ghcup install ghc 9.2.4`  and then `ghcup set ghc 9.2.4` so the ghc version in the PATH is the right one. `hls` should work then. Also, avoid installing `ghc` via `stack` or some problems may arise. if you have installed `stack` with `ghcup` I think there should be no problem, as long as you use `stack-2.9.1`.

Comment: Btw, the reason `ghc-9.2.5` is the recommended version is because a bug on Apple's M1 chip in the previous version. Also, if you want the best developer experience on haskell I'd _recommend_ using `ghc-8.10.7` as all `hls` plugins works perfectly in such version. I moved to `9.2` series because of some language extension I'd like to use but the overall experience is a little bit worse.

Comment: HLS-1.9.0.0 is now out, which does support GHC-9.2.5.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell the Haskell extension which version of ghc it should use via your settings.json:

```json
{
    "haskell.toolchain": {
     "ghc": "9.2.4"
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell#setting-a-specific-toolchain)